# Using make with noun followed by adjective

Tags: sentence-construction

Can we use the below-mentioned statement to express the following idea: "Celia infuriated Rudolf. Thus, he didn't help Celia."

> Celia made Rudolf angry. Thus, Rudolf didn't help her.

In nutshell, I want to know whether we can use the construct **"make + noun +adjective"**. If yes, can we also use the following statement in a similar format:

> Celia made Rudolf calm. Thus, Rudolf agreed to help her.

or it should be:

> Celia calmed down Rudolf. Thus, Rudolf agreed to help her.

I have only seen one sentence in this format which is used mostly, but not others that I mentioned above:

> Celia made Rudolf happy. She is a nice person.

Comment: You're on to something interesting. I wouldn't say "make Rudolph calm" unless I meant he became calmer in general, in the long run. But I would say "make Rudolph angry" for the short run... I wonder if it depends on the adjective.

Comment: The short answer is yes. *make* is a complex-transitive verb, so it can take a direct object and a predicative complement.

Comment: We only use *thus* to mean *consequently* in contexts of logical inference, not of causality.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for pointing out this mistake. I think I can replace "thus" with "As a result" in these sentences.

Comment: Yes -- or just *so*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the grammatical structure **make + noun + adjective complement** like in *He made me happy/sad/angry/upset....*.

- You can also see this http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/make